# Radius of Convergence and Interval of Convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

The questions ask to find the ROC and IOC of:
$$\frac{1}{k^{1.001}}(5^{0.5}x)^k$$

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please check to see if I correctly converted your expression to $\LaTeX$. Please learn how to do it yourself next time at: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/4583

Comment: Ratio Test works fine. You may be more comfortable temporarily letting $t=5^{0.5}x$.

Comment: I will thank you! the expression is correct. I attempted the ratio and root test. The root test would not work because the first multiplayer would be left with a power of 1/k even thought the power of the second term would cancel. am I correct? i am also not sure how to apply the ratio test in this case since I can't calculate (K+1)^1.001.

Answer (score 2):

Both  the ratio and root test are applicable for this series. Rewrite $$\sum\limits_{k =1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^{1.001}}(5^{0.5}x)^k = \sum\limits_{k =1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\sqrt{5})^k}{k^{1.001}}x^k = \sum\limits_{k =1}^{\infty}a_k x^k$$ with $a_k=\dfrac{(\sqrt{5})^k}{k^{1.001}}.$ Then radius of convergence is 
$$ {R}={\lim\limits_{k \to\infty} {\dfrac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}}} = \lim\limits_{k \to\infty} {\dfrac{(\sqrt{5})^k}{k^{1.001}}\cdot\dfrac{(k+1)^{1.001}}{(\sqrt{5})^{k+1}}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}},$$
since $\lim\limits_{k \to\infty}{\dfrac{(k+1)^{1.001}}{k^{1.001}}}=\lim\limits_{k \to\infty}{\left(\dfrac{k+1}{k}\right)^{1.001}}=\left(\lim\limits_{k \to\infty}{\dfrac{k+1}{k}}\right)^{1.001}=1.$

Comment: Thank you! two quick questions. 1) isn't the ratio test ak+1/ak? and also 2) could you please explain why the the last line is true?

Comment: actually I figured out the answer to both the questions thank you!

Comment: By the ratio test the series $\sum\limits_{k =1}^{\infty}a_k x^k$ converges  if ${\lim\limits_{k \to\infty} {\lvert\dfrac{a_{k+1}x^{k+1}}{a_kx^k}}\rvert}<1 \Rightarrow \vert x\vert < \lim\limits_{k \to\infty} {\lvert \dfrac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}\rvert }  = R.$ The last line implies from the continuity of power function.